# How can I trace a longer callstack?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm using this to show the callstack:

```
throw new Error("show me");
```

But I'd like to print a longer (deeper) stack because the current one do not show me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see more with `Error.getStackTrace()`, it's probably because there is nothing more in the stack. Except for private internal player calls like [Render] etc.

Look at the deepest item in the call stack, it's probably an event handler of some sort. If so, you can't dig deeper than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stack trace as a string and log it to a file or show it in a text field.

```
var e:Error = new Error();
var trace:String = e.getStackTrace();

someTextField.text = trace;
```

Edit:
Using Flash Develop I threw an error and was able to see more than 17 steps of the stack trace :

```
Error
    at Main/func14()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:100]
    at Main/func13()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:93]
    at Main/func12()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:88]
    at Main/func11()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:83]
    at Main/func10()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:78]
    at Main/func9()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:73]
    at Main/func8()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:68]
    at Main/func7()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:63]
    at Main/func6()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:58]
    at Main/func5()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:53]
    at Main/func4()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:49]
    at Main/func3()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:44]
    at Main/func2()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:39]
    at Main/func1()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:34]
    at Main/onCreationComplete()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:29]
    at Main/___Main_Application1_creationComplete()[C:\Users\SGU\Desktop\barisu\misc\flex4test\src\Main.mxml:5]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1818]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:842]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

Comment: Maybe try with flash develop. I could see very long stack traces with it just fine.